# How to switch from root to my unix user and solve (code .) command issue?

Tags: sudo, su, visual-studio-code, user-default

When I open ubuntu(wsl) on windows , usually, it opens as karim_123 user and not as root user. But this time it opened as a root user. How can I return back to my unix linux account(karim_123)? I used **su - karim_123** command but when I close the terminal and reopen it, it opens as root user again so I have to switch back to my user(karim_123) every time I open ubuntu terminal. Additionally, I’m not capable of using **code .** command anymore to open my files in VS code. So it is very annoying and I can’t work on my projects!

Comment: The answer would be: just log as karim_123 and not as root. But the reality is your problem is about how to use WSL, a Windows feature which would be better dealt with at https://superuser.com/ not here which is about Unix/Linux, not Windows.

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Why Has My Ubuntu Started Defaulting To Root User On Startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427355/why-has-my-ubuntu-started-defaulting-to-root-user-on-startup-duel-running-wind/1427752#1427752)